# how can i make wrap text in GWT. I dont want one cell data to overflow into other cell destroying its boundaries

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

[image: check highlighted block with red color]

Please check image for reference. My requirement is to limit this text in the cell so that it does not remove partition line of next cell even when text is long.
I am using rich text editor in gwt 2.1.
I dont want one cell data to overflow into other cell destroying its boundaries

Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using:

```
label.setOverflow(Overflow.HIDDEN);
```

HIDDEN

public static final Overflow HIDDEN
Content that extends beyond the widget's width or height is clipped (hidden).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a CSS style to your table. For example:

```
.myTable td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use this?

```
pricate ListGrid grid;

grid.setFixedRecordHeights(false); // Will make sure that your rows can be resized.
grid.setWrapCells(true); // Will make the text at the end of your rows wrap to the next line
```